# find substring with count and return even frequency substring list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have one following question and write a function for it. can anyone give me some suggestion how my code can be better and better way to handle to build up return list with even frequency?

> One message system contains two device type message that each message is formatted with device type identifier with
>   device id and message count. Write a function to parse the message based on device type and message count and return
>   a list with each device id in even message frequency
>   rule: input string: message
>   device identifier
>   1:iOS device ID identifier: start with 'I' following with 3 character, total length is 4 character
>   2:Android device ID identifier: start with 'A' following with 2 character, total length is 3 character
>   3:message count is following by device id until next device ID
>   ex:
>   input: Asq2: {'Asq': 2} Asq with 2 message count
>   output: ['Asq', 'Asq']
>
> input: Akb2IAld3: ID: {'Akb': 2, 'IAld2': 3}  Akb with 2 message count,  IAld with 3 message count
>   output: ['Akb', 'IAld', 'Akb', 'IAld', 'IAld']
>
> input: Aqp1Iasd2Aqp4IAbd1: {'Aqp': 5, 'Iasd': 2, 'IAbd': 1}
>   output: ['Aqp', 'Iasd', 'IAbd', 'Aqp', 'Iasd', 'Aqp', 'Aqp', 'Aqp']

```py
from typing import List


def parse_message(string) -> List:
    i, j, ids_map, n, ids = 0, 0, dict(), len(string), ''

    while i < n:
        if string[i] in ('I', 'A') or i == n - 1:
            if ids:
                if i == n - 1:
                    ids_map[ids] = ids_map.get(ids, 0) + int(string[j:])
                else:
                    ids_map[ids] = ids_map.get(ids, 0) + int(string[j:i])
            j = i + 4 if string[i] == 'I' else i + 3
            ids = string[i:j]
            i = j - 1
        i += 1
    res = []
    while any(i > 0 for i in ids_map.values()):
        for k, v in ids_map.items():
            if v > 0:
                res.append(k)
                ids_map[k] -= 1
    return res
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is really hard to understand. When I read the description I noticed three steps:

1. Extract ID and message count.
2. Total duplicate message counts.
3. Return a round robin of these IDs.

You've got 1&2 mangled together, and 3 nicely by itself.

Since you're using Python, it's easier to read iterator based approaches to these things. Firstly you can replace your step 3 with a recipe from the `itertools` standard library. All you need to do is call `itertools.repeat` beforehand.

It's not immediately clear what your code is doing when you've mangled indexed iteration with business logic, with step 2 as well. And so I suggest re-writing it. You know the data will come in the form `{type}{message}{amount}`, where the type and amount has a length of 1, and message is either 2 or 3. And so to extract the messages and amounts you can just use `next`/`islice` on an iterator. Using a `try` `while` loop. After this totaling the message counts is simple.

Also if you're going to use `typing` you should use mypy too, and put type information on both the arguments and return types.

from typing import List, Iterator, Tuple, Sequence, TypeVar
    import itertools

```
MESSAGE_LENGTH = {
    'I': 3,
    'A': 2
}

TValue = TypeVar('TValue')


def roundrobin(*iterables: Tuple[Sequence[TValue], ...]) -> Iterator[TValue]:
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    num_active = len(iterables)
    nexts = itertools.cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)
    while num_active:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            # Remove the iterator we just exhausted from the cycle.
            num_active -= 1
            nexts = itertools.cycle(itertools.islice(nexts, num_active))


def extract_messages(input: Iterator[str]) -> Iterator[Tuple[str, int]]:
    input = iter(input)
    message_type = next(input)
    while True:
        length = MESSAGE_LENGTH[message_type]
        message = ''.join([message_type] + list(itertools.islice(input, length)))
        message_type = next(input)
        number = []
        try:
            while message_type not in MESSAGE_LENGTH:
                number += [message_type]
                message_type = next(input)
        except StopIteration:
            break
        finally:
            yield message, int(''.join(number))


def parse_message(string: str) -> List[str]:
    message_counts = {}
    for message, amount in extract_messages(string):
        message_counts.setdefault(message, 0)
        message_counts[message] += amount

    return list(roundrobin(*(
        itertools.repeat(key, amount)
        for key, amount in message_counts.items()
    )))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(parse_message('Akb2IAld3'))
    print(parse_message('Aqp1Iasd2Aqp4IAbd1'))
    print(parse_message('Aqp1Iasd2Aqp4IAbd10'))
```

Comment: thanks for feedback. however need to clarify that length of message count does not have to be 1, we may have input like `Akb2000IAld300`

Comment: @A.Lee I don't see that in the examples or text you gave in your original post. It's also easy to change my code to account for that.

Comment: understand, again, great feedback and lots of great point. thank you

Comment: @A.Lee Please see the updated code to handle that. In the future I'd recommend that you link to challenge descriptions so these errors don't happen again. :)